# Python plotting multiple graph

Tags: python, plot

I'm coding with IPython with this code:

```
import seaborn as sns

data.boxplot( return_type='axes', column = 'retlog')

data.hist( column='retlog')

sm.qqplot( data['retlog'].dropna(), line = 's')
```

First, I have one problem with the plot, sm.qqplot is plot twice I don't know why. (one time at the begining and one time at the end)

Second, I'd like to plot the boxplot/hist/qqplot in like two on the left and one on the right, not all them in a row.

Thanks for helping